# Getting substring from string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, substring, trim

I have a string "abcdefg-this-is-a-test" and I want to delete the first 6 characters of the string. This is what I am trying:

```
char contentSave2[180] = "abcdefg-this-is-a-test";
strncpy(contentSave2, contentSave2+8, 4);
```

No luck so far, processor gets stuck and resets itself.
Any help will be appreaciated.

Question: How can I trim down a string in C?

////EDIT////
I also tried this:

```
memcpy(contentSave2, &contentSave2[6], 10);
```

Doesn't work, same problem.

Comment: What is `contentSave`? It is not defined

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I am just using 1 string array, see edit.

Comment: Just sum it: _http://ideone.com/5zXUbn_

Comment: "String array" is very unfortunate terminology. It's a string, and it's an array (of characters, forming the string). It's not a "string array" until it's an array of strings.

Comment: @Guedes Thank you, this gives the correct output, but how do I store this output into the contentSave2 string?

Comment: I actually don't see any problem with your code. It should work.

Comment: @sdd Can you give us your complete code? The error must be elsewhere because the two lines you posted should work (despite the fact that other solutions exist)

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, it shouldn't. This is UB.

Comment: The second snippet is UB, the first one is not.. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If no more info is going to be posted, I am voting to close as non-reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first code snippet is that it copies the middle four characters to the beginning of the string, and then stops.

Unfortunately, you cannot expand it to cover the entire string, because in that case the source and output buffers would overlap, causing UB:

> [If the strings overlap, the behavior is undefined.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy)

Overlapping buffers is the problem with your second attempt: `memcpy` does not allow overlapping buffers, so the behavior is undefined.

If all you need is to remove characters at the beginning of the string, you do not need to copy it at all: simply take the address of the initial character, and use it as your new string:

```
char *strWithoutPrefix = &contentSave2[8];
```

For copying of strings from one buffer to another use `memcpy`:

```
char middle[5];
memcpy(middle, &contentSave2[8], 4);
middle[4] = '\0'; // "this"
```

For copying potentially overlapping buffers use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove):

```
char contentSave2[180] = "abcdefg-this-is-a-test";
printf("%s\n", contentSave2);
memmove(contentSave2, contentSave2+8, strlen(contentSave2)-8+1);
printf("%s\n", contentSave2);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/K2V6En)

Comment: Can you please explain the first paragraph? I actually failing to see the problem with OPs code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `strncpy` is often used, incorrectly, with strings of variable length. The biggest problem with that is that you must remember to null-terminate the resulting string in the end. [Here is an article explaining what's wrong with using `n` functions when working with regular strings.](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/)

Comment: But what is the problem in the question? I don't see it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I edited the answer. The problem with his edited code is that the buffers overlap, so `strncpy` is no longer applicable.

Comment: I would argue that there is no overlap in his code.

Comment: In the first snippet they don't overlap... It is copying 4 bytes with offset of 8.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Fixed.

Comment: Do you agree there is no problem in the original code (i.e. no UB)? Because I don't see why *The problem with your first....* is actually a problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The first example has no UB, so its only problem is that it does not do what OP wants it to do (i.e. it does not remove the prefix from the string).

Answer (score 3):

```
int len=strlen(content2save);
for(i=6;i<len;i++)
   content2save[i-6]=content2save[i];

content2save[i-6]='\0'
```

This will delete first 6 charcters . Based on requirement you may modify your code. If you want to use an inbuilt function try [memmove](http://home.fhtw-berlin.de/~junghans/cref/MAN/memmove.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use pointer because `contentSave2` here is also a pointer to a char array plus this will be quick and short.

```
char* ptr = contentSave2 + 6;
```

`ptr[0]` will be equal to  `contentSave2[6]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**memmove**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) function.

It is specially used when source and destination memory addresses overlap.

Small word of advice, try to avoid copying to and from overlapping source and destination. It is simply a buggen.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char contentSave2[180] = "abcdefg-this-is-a-test";
    strncpy(contentSave2, contentSave2+8, 4);
    printf("%s\n", contentSave2);
    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest posting the rest of your code because your issue is elsewhere. As others pointed out, watch out for overlap when you use `strncpy` though in this specific case it should works.